# Effect Size of CLMM

Tags: regression, r, mixed-model, ordinal-data, effect-size

I am conducting an omnibus analysis of a CLMM model from the `ordinal` package. I passed the CLMM model to the function `Anova.clmm()` from the `RVAideMemoire` package. The output table includes the model parameters, associated LR chi-squared statistics, and p-values.

Is there a way to assess the "effect size" or "strength of significance" for each model parameter from this point? Exponentiating the coefficients from the model does not produce intuitive results.

UPDATE
[Cross-posted here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/1birl4f/effect_size_of_clmm/)